# Delphi 7 WSDL Importer does not retrieve types from WCF service

Tags: wcf, delphi, soap, wsdl, delphi-7

I am developing a WCF service (with .NET Framework 4.5), which should simplify the interoperability between clients developed in other languages and my SDK.

The problem is that when using the WSDL Importer providing the WSDL URL from service, it can only bring the Interfaces without any Type.

I tested with others URLs present in tutorials on the internet and the problem does not exist.

For example, when using the WSDL importer to http://www.webservicex.net/WeatherForecast.asmx?WSDL, Interfaces and Types are both brought.

The problem occurs even in a clean project Application WCF, testing with his `IService1`, and `Service1` `CompositeType` (I'm using Visual Studio 2015).

In tests with Java clients, everything went well. But it was Java 8. Which leads me to suspect that it is a communication protocol version problem or something like this, but I can not know exactly where is the problem.

Comment: My money is on the WSDL importer itself. That version of Delphi is now some 14 years old, and I seem to recall seeing other questions here suggesting that there were issues with the WSDL importer in that version.

Comment: Did you install the Delphi SOAP Runtime and Importer Update from http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/24535 ?